Safari 17.6 ignores origins from`style-src-elem` CSP directive, instead complaining they're neither in `style-src` nor `default-src`
This is a problem solely occuring with Safari (my current version being 17.6). Neither Chrome nor Firefox show any issues with this CSP header value.
The issue is about the style-src-elem directive, but for completeness sake, the full Content-Security-Policy - formatted over multiple lines for readability - is this:
Content-Security-Policy:
        default-src 'none'                                          
  ;        base-uri 'self'                                          
  ;     connect-src 'self'                                          
  ;        font-src 'self'                                          
                    https://fonts.gstatic.com                       
  ;     form-action 'self'                                          
  ; frame-ancestors 'none'                                          
  ;         img-src 'self'                                          
                    data:                                           
  ; script-src-attr 'unsafe-inline'                                 
  ; script-src-elem 'self'                                          
  ;  style-src-attr 'unsafe-inline'                                 
  ;  style-src-elem 'self'                                          
                    'unsafe-inline'                     
                    https://fonts.googleapis.com

The Safari console reports:

Refused to load https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlinedbecause it appears in neither thestyle-srcdirective nor thedefault-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
Refused to load https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swapbecause it appears in neither thestyle-srcdirective nor thedefault-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
Refused to load https://example.com/app/styles.cssbecause it appears in neither thestyle-srcdirective nor thedefault-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Where the "offending" origins are:
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/app/"/>
    ...
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
  </head>
...

According to the MDN CSP:style-src-elem spec:

The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) style-src-elem directive specifies valid sources for stylesheet <style> elements and <link> elements with rel="stylesheet".

Which AFAICT is exactly what I'm using this directive for.
Also, MDN's browser compatibility chart claims that Safari has full support for this directive from version 15.4 onward.
So, why does this newer Safari appear to ignore the style-src-elem directive?
Adding a style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com directive does appear to be a "fix", but I don't like the redundancy.
Similarly, just replacing style-src-elem with style-src also "fixes", but I don't like using fallbacks when more specific directives that should do the job exist.
And in any case, neither "fix" brings me any closer to understanding why the original doesn't work as intended in the first place.

"Also, MDN's browser compatibility chart claims that Safari has full support for this directive from version 15.4 onward." - that mustn't necessarily mean that they did not manage to introduce a bug in later versions. I'd maybe use browserstack or something like that, to verify it actually works as intended in 15.4 then.

@CBroe, Browserstack allows me to go as far back as Safari 15.6 before crossing the 15.4 landmark, but the behaviour remains unchanged.

Have just wrestled with this over BrowserStack. It turns out that several versions of Safari, both mobile and desktop, refuse to recognize style-src-elem across any number of versions, and only work as expected with style-src. So it's clearly not a recent bug. I find myself wondering if there's a glitch that follows from a particular combo of CSP directives. Not finding an explanation, nor can be bothered right now with trialing by reduction. Also reported here: https://auto-bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276931 ... and here: https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/24299
